# Installation progress bar php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple installer that's divided in segments, not by syntax, but just by logic. Here's how it works:

```
if ($_POST['install'] == "Install")
{
// fetches user values

// creates tables 

// creates some files 

// creates some emails

// inserts relevant stuff into the database

// finishes
}
```

The code is too long and unnecessary for this question. Each of those steps counts as 20% complete for the installation, how would I make a progress bar displaying the info to the user? I'd like this for two reasons, one is for them to keep track, other is for them to know they shouldn't close the browser tab before it's done.

Now my idea is to assign a variable to each part of the code, for instance `$done = 20%` in the first, `$done = 40%` in the second etc, and simply show progress bar based on that variable. The the only thing I don't know is how to show the progress bar?

Thanks

Comment: How long does the process actually take? Is it all done in one request or is it a "wizard" style installation? (looks like it installs all at once)

Comment: It creates 10 tables, inserts some data, hooks into cpanel to create some emails, changes a few file names and creates 1 file. I'd say top about 1-2 minutes, depending on the load of hosting machine. It's all done in one step, you fill out a form and press install =)

Answer (score 2):

My recommended solution:

Create separate ajax requests for each step in your process like so...

```
// do first step
$.ajax({
   url: myUrl + '?step=1',
   success: function() {
     // update progress bar 20%
   }
});

// do second step
$.ajax({
   url: myUrl + '?step=2',
   success: function() {
     // update progress bar 40%
   }
});

// etc.
```

If you want to be DRY, try this:

```
var steps = 5;

for (var i = 1; i <= steps; i++) {
    $.ajax({
       url: myUrl + '?step=' + i;
       success: function() {
         // update success incrementally
       }
    });
}
```

With jQuery UI progressbar:

```
$(function() {

    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
      value: 0
    });

    var steps = 5;

    for (var i = 1; i <= steps; i++) {
        $.ajax({
           url: myUrl + '?step=' + i;
           success: function() {
             // update success incrementally
             $("#progressbar").progressbar('value', i * 20);
           }
        });
    }

});
```

Ref. http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#default

Comment: Another upside for this method is that each section is standalone. If one fails, you haven't lost everything. You can restart where it left off.

Comment: Sounds easy enough. If I was to say I know literally 0 ajax, how would you suggest I show progress bar based on your code here? Thank you!

Comment: The way you have the code would cause all the ajax functions to be started at once, essentially execute each step at the same time, when they should be done in step, one after other is done.

Comment: @SamFisher I updated the answer with a jQuery UI progressbar implementation.

Comment: @PatrickEvans True, so it would probably be best to go with the for loop method.  If concurrency is still an issue, you would be able to try setting `async` to false in the `$.ajax()` method.

Comment: no, the exact opposite you do not want to do the for loop option, as that is the one that will cause them all to execute at once since as soon as `$.ajax()` is called the request starts, shouldnt use async:false that has the potential to freeze users browser.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to store the progress value in a db or a key-value storage system such as APC, Memcache or Redis. And then retrieve the progress with an ajax query.

A good jquery plugin is [progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) bar from jQuery-ui, and you can use json to encode the progress value:

```
// GET /ajax/get-status.json
{
    "progress":10,
    "error":"",
    "warning":""
}
```

The page:

```
<div id="error" style="color: red"></div>
<div id="warning" style="color: yellow"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">   
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

            function updateProgress() {
                jQuery.getJSON("/ajax/get-status.json", function(response) {

                    if (response.error) {
                        $("#error").html( response.error );
                        return;
                    } else {
                        $("#progressbar").progressbar( 'value', parseInt( response.progress ) ); // Add the new value to the progress bar
                        $("#message").html( response.message );
                        $("#warning").html( response.warning );
                        if(parseInt( response.progress ) < 100){
                            setTimeout(updateProgress, 1);
                        }
                    }
                  });
            }

            updateProgress();
        });           
</script>
```

Comment: I was looking into APC, but from what I understand, users would have to install it manually, and I'm trying to make this as easy as possible. I'm going to look into all the solutions offered here and implement one, thank you =)

Comment: APC is installed on the server end

Comment: if you don't want use db or any key-value system you can always do it with sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTML5 progress bar.

Send ajax request and return the percent complete.
Change the progress tag's value.

```
<progress id='p' max="100" value="50"></progress>
```

Comment: Although this is an answer, it is a terribly useless one.

Comment: How so? He wasn't sure how to display a progress bar.

Comment: It's good and simple, I might be able to echo that html throughout php and simply show it on screen. Testing atm =)